# How to only update tables cells if null using PDO and arrays

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I can't seem to figure out a method to only update cells that contain a null value. Utilizing this statement (post initial database update) to mimic initial data into an adjacent cells so as data changes it has a base reference.

Just need to find a method to only allow these cells to update once. I've set them to NULL as default. Different data sets are collected daily into the same table with unique time/date id's.

```
$data        = "http://192.168.1.1/data.xml";
$domdoc      = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc      ->load($data);
$xml         = new Domxpath($domdoc);

$unitCount = $xml->query("//data/units")->length;

//get unit id's
$id_array = array();
$id = $xml->query('//data/units//@id');
foreach($id as $item){
  array_push($id_array, $item->nodeValue);
};

for ($i=0; $i < $unitCount; $i++){

  $id_db = $id_array[$i];

  //get unit angle
  unset($angle_array);
  $angle_array = array();
  $angle = $xml->query('//data/units[@id="'$id_array[$i]'"]//@angle');
  foreach($angle as $item){
    array_push($angle_array, $item->nodeValue);
  };

  //get unit speed
  unset($speed_array);
  $speed_array = array();
  $speed = $xml->query('//data/units[@id="'$id_array[$i]'"]//@speed');
  foreach($speed as $item){
    array_push($speed_array, $item->nodeValue);
  };

  //get unit charge
  unset($charge_array);
  $charge_array = array();
  $charge = $xml->query('//data/units[@id="'$id_array[$i]'"]//@charge');
  foreach($charge as $item){
    array_push($charge_array, $item->nodeValue);
  };

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE INTO `action-data` (
    `id`,
    `angle_start`,
    `angle`,
    `speed_start`,
    `speed`,
    `charge_start`,
    `charge`
  ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->execute(array(
    $id_db,
    $angle_db,
    $angle_db,
    $speed_db,
    $speed_db,
    $charge_db,
    $charge_db
  ));
}


| id  |angle_start|angle|speed_start|speed|charge_start|charge|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| a4b |     1     |  2  |      0    |  5  |    100     |  31  |
| a4b |     3     |  7  |      0    |  4  |    95      |  29  |
| a4b |     1     |  5  |      0    |  5  |    100     |  4   |
| a4b |     3     |  4  |      0    |  2  |    97      |  36  |

            ^                  ^                ^
             \                 |               /
              These values default NULL and
              should be set once upon first input
              but ignored on future inputs if not == NULL.
```

Edit: added an example that better illustrates the what, how, and why.

Comment: Post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Thanks, tried to clarify what I'm looking to accomplish. The lack of documentation leads me to believe I'm using the wrong approach entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a syntax error in your array declaration. Also, and I know this is nit-picky, the result of `$dbh->prepare()` is a prepared statement, not SQL, so maybe rename your variable so that it isn't confusing for yourself or other developers in the future:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("REPLACE INTO `action-data` (
  `angle_start`,
  `speed_start`,
  `temp_start`,
  `direction_start`,
  `charge_start`
) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->execute(array(
  $angle_start_db,
  $speed_start_db,
  $temp_start_db,
  $direction_start_db,
  $charge_start_db
));
```

If that still doesn't work, we may need to look at your declaration of `$dbh` to see if it's configured properly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I cut a lot of the statement out to keep it short and simple and left a stray comma in there. Just looking for a method to update all values only if currently value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how PDO Works but i just read in some where so i just give you hint for updating with PDO On NULL

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE `access_users` SET `contact_first_name` = :firstname, `contact_surname` = :surname, `contact_email` = :email, `telephone` = :telephone WHERE `user_name` = :user_name');
$stmt->bindValue(':param', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```